# JQuery Cookies with dynamic div ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I hope you guys can give me a push in the right direction as this problem has been eating me up all day now..

What I'm basicly trying to accomplish is this. I have several div's on a page that can be collapsed independently from eachother with the use of a button. Every div has it's own specific ID, generated with a string of static text, and a numeric value based on a auto-incremented database-value. This ensures I never have two div's with the same ID on one page. To target each specific div with Javascript (jQuery) I use the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/LU7QA/0/

This works really well and does what it's supposed to do. Only there is one problem. On every page frefresh, every div that was opened is closed. Everything resets, and that's why I want to use JQuery Cookies in this construction. Only problem is, I know how it works, but I can't get it to work in this specific construction as it has to deal with a completely unique ID every time and needs to store the values of that particular ID.

As seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/LU7QA/1/

I tried to fiddle around with it but I can't seem to get it working properly and I'm starting to lose my sight on the problem..

```
<div>
    <button class="button_slide" value="1">Show hide</button>
</div>
    <div id="slidingDiv_1" class="slidingDiv">Stuff</div>

<div>
    <button class="button_slide" value="2">Show hide</button>
</div>
    <div id="slidingDiv_2" class="slidingDiv">Stuff</div>


function initMenu() {

$(".slidingDiv").hide();

    // Toggle Field

$(".button_slide").click(function(){

    //alert($(this).val()); debugging purposes

    var sliding_id = $(this).val();

    div_sliding_id = '#slidingDiv_'+sliding_id;

    $(div_sliding_id).next().slideToggle('slow', function() {

    $.cookie(div_sliding_id, $(this).is(':hidden') ? "closed" : "open");                 
    return false;
    });
});

$('.button_slide').each(function() { 
    var sliding_id = $(this).val();
    div_sliding_id = '#slidingDiv_'+sliding_id;
    if ($.cookie(div_sliding_id) == "open")  $(this).next().show(); 
});

}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {initMenu();});
```

Comment: Have you thought about using `localStorage` instead perhaps?

Comment: Actually no. I'm still relatively new to this, and I learn every day. I've ne ver worked with cookies before actually and localStorage is a new phenomenon for me. But I'm gonna read into it! Thanks.

Comment: In your particular instance, I would work with localStorage since your data is all client side. Here's a link to get you started: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

Answer (score -1):

May you have missed a dot on the last *button_slide* declaration?

Btw, look at https://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/